# Código só funciona para uma das div´s

Tags: javascript, html, css, style

Olá, estou começando a aprender programação agora e preciso de ajuda para resolver um probleminha e estou com um problema que acredito ser fácil resolver.
Este é o problema:

```js
function Antes() {
    document.getElementById('ant').style.backgroundColor = "#c3c3c4";
}

function antes() {
    document.getElementById('ant').style.backgroundColor = "black";
}

function Depois() {
    document.getElementById('pro').style.backgroundColor = "#c3c3c4";
}

function depois() {
    document.getElementById('pro').style.backgroundColor = "black";
}

function Close() {
    document.getElementById('close').style.color = "#c3c3c4";
}

function fechar() {
    document.getElementById('close').style.color = "white";
}
```

```html
<div class="lbox" id="img1">
    <div class="box_image"></div>
        <a href="#img6" class="btn" id="ant" onmousemove="Antes()" onmouseout="antes()">&#171;</a>
     <a href="#img2" class="btn" id="pro" onmousemove="Depois()" onmouseout="depois()">&#187;</a>
     <a href="" class="btn" id="close" onmousemove="Close()" onmouseout="fechar()">X</a>
     <img src="imagens/combate-ao-aedes-aegypti-2.jpg" alt="" id="imgm1">
    </div>


</div>

<div class="lbox" id="img2">
    <div class="box_image">
        <a href="#img1" class="btn" id="ant" onmousemove="Antes()" onmouseout="antes()">&#171;</a>
     <a href="#img3" class="btn" id="pro"  onmousemove="Depois()" onmouseout="depois()">&#187;</a>
     <a href="" class="btn" id="close" onmousemove="Close()" onmouseout="fechar()">X</a>
     <img src="imagens/dengue-cuidados.png" alt="" id="imgm2">
</div>
```

A intenção é fazer com que a `a href` mude a cor do background quando passe o mouse em cima

Consegui com esse código realizar essa ação em somente com as "a href" da div#img1 (no caso a#ant, a#pro e a#close da div#img1) ,mas nas outras div's não.

Comment: Quando se quer estilizar algo, recomenda-se fortemente utilizar somente CSS para tal ação, utilizando o mínimo de JavaScript possível. O que você quer fazer é possível utilizando apenas CSS.

Comment: se usar a pseudoclass `: hover` não vai precisar de nada de `javascript`

Answer (score 0):

Pode fazer isso usando somente `css`:

```css
.btn:hover {
   background-color: #c3c3c4
}

.btn-ant {
  background-color: black
}

.btn-pro {
  background-color: black
}

.btn-close {
  background-color: white
}
```

```html
<div class="lbox" id="img1">
    <div class="box_image"></div>
    <a href="#img1" class="btn btn-ant">&#171;</a>
    <a href="#img3" class="btn btn-pro">&#187;</a>
    <a href="" class="btn btn-close">X</a>
    <img src="imagens/combate-ao-aedes-aegypti-2.jpg" alt="" id="imgm1">
</div>

<div class="lbox" id="img2">
    <div class="box_image">
    <a href="#img1" class="btn btn-ant">&#171;</a>
    <a href="#img3" class="btn btn-pro">&#187;</a>
    <a href="" class="btn btn-close">X</a>
    <img src="imagens/dengue-cuidados.png" alt="" id="imgm2">
</div>
```

Para isso, usei nomes de classes, para evitar usar "ID", que deve ser único, e para o evento "mousemove" usei a pseudoclass `:hover`, que é ativada quando o mouse estiver sobre o elemento.